# how to combine lists in python3

Tags: python

I have 4 lists:

```
a1 = [1,3,5]
a2 = ['apple','pear','banana']
b1 = [2,4,6]
b2 = ['yes','no','maybe']
```

Where the numbers are the positions of the words. I want to combine these lists to get one list which would be:

```
combined_list = ['apple', 'yes', 'pear', 'no','banana', 'maybe']
```

Thanks!

Comment: Are the positions always evenly spaced and/or ordered? Since they aren't indices, are they at least guaranteed to be consecutive and a complete range?

Comment: Why do the numbers not start at 0? What should happen if the same number appears in both lists? What should happen if a number appears that doesn't make sense (for example, it is negative, or too large for the total number of words)? What should happen if there is a gap in the overall range of the numbers? What should happen if the amount of numbers doesn't match the amount of words? Most importantly, *why* do you want to do this?

Comment: Also: please do not use irrelevant tags. There is no reason to suspect that your operating system is relevant to the problem. Finally: Welcome to Stack Overflow. please read [ask] and note that this is not a code-writing service. Simply describing a problem is not sufficient. You are expected to try to solve the problem yourself first, and then *ask a* **specific** *question*, ideally starting with a question word like "how" or "why" and ending with a question mark (`?`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do it using `zip()`, sorting according to the given 'index' and then choosing the second element in a list comprehension:

```
c1 = a1+b1
c2 = a2+b2
[i[1] for i in sorted(zip(c1, c2), key=lambda x: x[0])]
```

Output:

```
['apple', 'yes', 'pear', 'no', 'banana', 'maybe']
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a dictionary using the lists and sort the values based on keys. Finally append them into a new list.

```
a1 = [1,3,5]
a2 = ['apple','pear','banana']
b1 = [2,4,6]
b2 = ['yes','no','maybe']

d = {}
for m,n in zip(a1, a2):
    d[m] = n
for x,y in zip(b1,b2):
    d[x] = y

list1 = []
for i in sorted(d.keys()):
    list1.append(d[i])
print(list1)
```

Comment: why is there a ```;``` in this?

Comment: It was a typo @Nin17. Thanks for pointing out. Also, just noticed your answer which is more crisper than mine!